# HTTPS Site: Load an external CSS over HTTP

Tags: javascript, https

I have a secure (HTTPS) web app which needs to load a custom stylesheet from an insecure (HTTP) origin (customer's own website). This is blocked by modern browsers, however I need a workaround because:

1) I cannot ask my customers to host their custom stylesheets on HTTPS. They don't have the know-how and some of them have policies about what hosts and regions stuff can be hosted in (ironically, not about HTTPS though).
  2) I obviously cannot ask the end user to disable security features in their browser.

I tried, loading stylesheets using `<style>@import url(...);</style>`, I tried creating an iframe with src="about:blank" and loading the stylesheet from within there, I tried XHR and fetch (but that will require CORS to be enabled on the remote host which I cannot reasonably expect).

Short of creating a secure proxy that will serve any stylesheet on the web, is there any other workaround I'm missing here?

Any sorcery to get my page to load a cross-origin stylesheet over HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a workaround to be able to load insecure resources on secure pages, it should be patched ASAP. No, the policy exists because without HTTPS on ***all*** resources, you're not truly secured. Any HTTP connection may be intercepted and man-in-the-middled, so the page is not secure. Even something minor like a stylesheet can undermine that security.

You *will* have to serve the stylesheet over HTTPS, and if your customers can't do it, you will have to do it for them.

Comment: "If there was a workaround to be able to load insecure resources on secure pages, it should be patched ASAP"
That makes sense. However, we can *explicitly* load insecure resources using XHR, even cross-domain. The policy exists (if I understand correctly) to prevent *inadvertently* loading insecure resources by using a stylesheet/script tag that can fall victim to MITM. This is a good policy. I've seen cases where the ISP injects JS into a page to show ads. But policies should set secure defaults yet allow the dev to override things for special cases. This is what I mean about a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps possible to download their CSS server-side, and serve it to your own users via HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same thing with a webapp that i builded. The real issue with what you want to do is the browser. It doesnt allow a secure connection to be spoiled by an insecure connection, especially when you want to inject something on that page. I used this technic:

```
document.createElement("link")
```

to inject. And with browser security being a big issue, I don't think you'll find a hack..
Best of luck! :)